# How to set int values as key in spring cache annotation

Tags: java, caching, key, spring-el, spring-cache

I want to use the int variable of this method as a key for cache the data returned for this method , but I did read that only I can use Long or Integer variables because that has the .toString method.

There is a some way to get the variable int as a kay with some command of Expression Language (spEL) ????

Here is my configuration , bu it doesnt work:

```
 @Cacheable(cacheNames="REQUIREMENT", 
 key="T(java.lang.String).valueOf(#requirementID)")  
 private Requirement getRequirement(final int requirementID, final 
 Connection connection)
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `Long` or `Integer` as recommanded by the documentation ?

Comment: This method has a lot of calls from many classes. If I change the value I fear that I could impact other processes.

Comment: "it doesnt work" is never enough information; exactly what problem are you having? Have you tried `new Integer(...).toString()`?